# Problemas al mostrar información de un webservices con Json

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, webservice

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Creé una aplicación que interactúa con una base de datos a través de unas webservice escritas en JSON. Es capaz de crear, modificar y eliminar. El problema está que cuando deseo realizar una consulta general o consulta por ID, los datos no están siendo llevados o mostrados en el XML sobre un `TextView` (Aún suponiendo que la consulta sí se realizó a nivel de código).

PD: El código lo extraje de un tutorial porque mi código lo he corrompido intentando alternativas

Código Java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button consultar;
Button consultarporid;
Button insertar;
Button actualizar;
Button borrar;
EditText idendificador;
EditText nombre;
EditText direccion;
TextView resultado;


// IP de mi Url
String IP = "http://bdandroidtuto.esy.es/";
// Rutas de los Web Services
String GET = IP + "/obtener_alumnos.php";
String GET_BY_ID = IP + "/obtener_alumno_por_id.php";
String UPDATE = IP + "/actualizar_alumno.php";
String DELETE = IP + "/borrar_alumno.php";
String INSERT = IP + "/insertar_alumno.php";

ObtenerWebService hiloconexion;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Enlaces con elementos visuales del XML

    consultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.consultar);
    consultarporid = (Button)findViewById(R.id.consultarid);
    insertar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insertar);
    actualizar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.actualizar);
    borrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.borrar);
    idendificador = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eid);
    nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enombre);
    direccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edireccion);
    resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado);

    // Listener de los botones

    consultar.setOnClickListener(this);
    consultarporid.setOnClickListener(this);
    insertar.setOnClickListener(this);
    actualizar.setOnClickListener(this);
    borrar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.consultar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(GET,"1");   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground

            break;
        case R.id.consultarid:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            String cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID + "?idalumno=" + idendificador.getText().toString();
            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"2");   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.insertar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(INSERT,"3",nombre.getText().toString(),direccion.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.actualizar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(UPDATE,"4",idendificador.getText().toString(),nombre.getText().toString(),direccion.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        case R.id.borrar:

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            hiloconexion.execute(DELETE,"5",idendificador.getText().toString());   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}

public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String cadena = params[0];
        URL url = null; // Url de donde queremos obtener información
        String devuelve ="";



        if(params[1]=="1"){    // Consulta de todos los alumnos

            try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){


                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                    // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a través de un
                    // StringBuilder.

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON



                    if (resultJSON=="1"){      // hay alumnos a mostrar
                        JSONArray alumnosJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("alumno");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                        for(int i=0;i<alumnosJSON.length();i++){
                            devuelve = devuelve + alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("idalumno") + " " +
                                    alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre") + " " +
                                    alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") + "\n";

                        }

                    }
                    else if (resultJSON=="2"){
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }


                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="2"){    // consulta por id

            try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){


                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                    // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a través de un
                    // StringBuilder.

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON=="1"){      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = devuelve + respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("idAlumno") + " " +
                                respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("nombre") + " " +
                                respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("direccion");

                    }
                    else if (resultJSON=="2"){
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }

                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="3"){    // insert

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("nombre", params[2]);
                jsonParam.put("direccion", params[3]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno insertado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "El alumno no pudo insertarse";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;


        }
        else if(params[1]=="4"){    // update

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("idalumno",params[2]);
                jsonParam.put("nombre", params[3]);
                jsonParam.put("direccion", params[4]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno actualizado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "El alumno no pudo actualizarse";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;

        }
        else if(params[1]=="5") {    // delete

            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                DataOutputStream printout;
                DataInputStream input;
                url = new URL(cadena);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConn.connect();
                //Creo el Objeto JSON
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("idalumno", params[2]);
                // Envio los parámetros post.
                OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode();


                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        //response+=line;
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON == "1") {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                        devuelve = "Alumno borrado correctamente";

                    } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                        devuelve = "No hay alumnos";
                    }

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return devuelve;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String s) {
        super.onCancelled(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        resultado.setText(s);
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }



}

}
```

Código XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rwa.jsontest.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar"
        android:id="@+id/consultar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar ID"
        android:id="@+id/consultarid" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insertar"
        android:id="@+id/insertar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Borrar"
        android:id="@+id/borrar" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Actualizar"
        android:id="@+id/actualizar" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Identificador"
        android:id="@+id/tid" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eid" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:id="@+id/tnombre" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enombre" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direccion"
        android:id="@+id/tdireccion" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edireccion" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Has probado si la consulta en verdad obtiene un json con datos...

Comment: Si te refieres a probar en la aplicación si obtienen datos eso nose hacerlo.. Lo que si puedo decir con propiedad que los  Json obtienen datos de la consulta y consulta por ID http://bdandroidtuto.esy.es/obtener_alumnos.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El servicio web esta regresando los datos correctamente, te recomiendo que coloques un punto de interrupción al momento que estas creando tu objeto JSON en la aplicación en la linea `JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());` aqui si colocas el puntero del mouse sobre la variable `result` te mostrara el contenido de la misma, si su contenido es distinto a null, pasará la linea sin problema, eso significa que la aplicación si obtiene la información.

En una `AsyncTask` se ejecutan 2 metodos principalmente si se quiere modificar la interface grafica despues de obtener una respuesta el servidor, `doInBackground()`y `onPostExecute()` hay que tener en cuenta que el método `doInBackground()` se ejecuta en un hilo diferente al de la interfaz gráfica por lo tanto aqui no podemos modificar nada referente a la interfaz, esto se hace en el siguiente metodo `onPostExecute()` que como su nombre lo dice se ejecuta despues de la llamada al servidor. Te dejo un ejemplo de un metodo similar que obtiene datos de un servidor y muestra el contenido en `TextView`.

```
public class consultarCliente extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //Variables globales
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    Context context;
    String apiCallUrl;
    int idCliente;

    //Dialogo de progreso
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public consultarCliente(Context context,int idCliente) {
        //Muestro un cuadro de dialogo de espera al usuario
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Extrayendo datos");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor espere...");
        progressDialog.show();
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
        apiCallUrl = context.getString(R.string.s_url_main) + context.getString(R.string.s_url_consultarCliente) + "?idCliente=" + idCliente; //Formo la URL al servidor, en tu caso bdandroidtuto.esy.es/obtener_alumnos.php
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //Hago la llamada al servidor
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(apiCallUrl);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //Si tuvo conexión exitosa con el servidor, obtenemos un status 200
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(data); //Creo mi objeto JSON con la información de mi cliente
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (jsonObject.getBoolean("estadoOperacion") && !jsonObject.getString("mensajeError").equals("No existe el cliente para el id solicitado")) {

                //Obtenemos los datos del cliente y los asignamos a mi objeto POJO
                JSONObject cliente = jsonObject.getJSONObject("ctlcliente");
                Ctlcliente cl = new Ctlcliente();
                cl.setCalleCliente(cliente.getString("callecliente"));
                cl.setCodigoPostalCliente(cliente.getString("codigopostalcliente"));
                cl.setColoniaCliente(cliente.getString("coloniacliente"));
                cl.setContactoCliente(cliente.getString("contactocliente"));
                cl.setCorreo1Cliente(cliente.getString("correo1cliente"));
                cl.setCorreo2Cliente(cliente.getString("correo2cliente"));
                cl.setDireccionEnvio1Cliente(cliente.getString("direccionenvio1cliente"));
                cl.setDireccionEnvio2Cliente(cliente.getString("direccionenvio2cliente"));
                cl.setDireccionEnvio3Cliente(cliente.getString("direccionenvio3cliente"));
                cl.setEstadoCliente(cliente.getString("estadocliente"));
                cl.setFormaEntregaCliente(cliente.getString("formaentregacliente"));
                cl.setHorarioLlamadaCliente(cliente.getString("horariollamadacliente"));
                cl.setIdCliente(cliente.getInt("idCliente"));
                cl.setLocalidadCliente(cliente.getString("localidadcliente"));
                cl.setMunicipioCliente(cliente.getString("municipiocliente"));
                cl.setNivelCliente(cliente.getString("nivelcliente"));
                cl.setNoExteriorCliente(cliente.getString("noexteriorcliente"));
                cl.setNoInteriorCliente(cliente.getString("nointeriorcliente"));
                cl.setNombreCliente(cliente.getString("nombrecliente"));
                cl.setObservacionesCliente(cliente.getString("observacionescliente"));
                cl.setPaisCliente(cliente.getString("paiscliente"));
                cl.setReferenciaCliente(cliente.getString("referenciacliente"));
                cl.setRfcCliente(cliente.getString("rfccliente"));
                cl.setSaldoCliente(cliente.getDouble("saldocliente"));
                cl.setTelefonoFijoCliente(cliente.getString("telefonofijocliente"));
                cl.setTelefonoMovilCliente(cliente.getString("telefonomovilcliente"));
                cl.setTipoCliente(cliente.getString("tipocliente"));
                colocaValoresCliente(cl);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void colocaValoresCliente(Cliente ctlcliente){
    //Inicializamos la interfaz
    txtNombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ui_cliente_nombre);
    txtRfc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ui_cliente_rfc);
    txtCorreo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ui_cliente_correo);
    txtDireccion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ui_cliente_direccion);
    txtTelefono = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ui_cliente_telefono);

    //Colocamos los valores
    txtNombre.setText(ctlcliente.getNombreCliente());
    txtRfc.setText(ctlcliente.getRfcCliente());
    txtCorreo.setText(ctlcliente.getCorreo1Cliente());
    txtDireccion.setText(ctlcliente.getDireccionEnvio1Cliente());
    txtTelefono.setText(ctlcliente.getTelefonoFijoCliente());
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta si quieres utilizar mi metodo como ejemplo que utilizo la libreria de apache para la llamada al servidor, la cual en las nuevas versiones ya esta deprecada al menos que la agreges manualmente en tu archivo `build.gradle` la siguiente dependencia:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.angelruiz.miapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. No lo he intentado con este ejemplo pero a primeras se me parece  a la solución de otra app que estoy elaborando con webservices; sin embargo yo soy un poco testarudo y ahora mas sabiendo, que gracias a lo que me estas explicando, la app esta regresando los datos correctamente y que la solución pasa por el onPostExecute. Seguiré pensando en la solución de mi metodo 

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta